# Chosen or Jquery sometimes does not load

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-chosen

Dynamically alterning DOM was working fine until I added Chosen and started doing them when the page loads.  Now when I test my page by repeatedly refreshing it, sometimes it will load correctly, and sometimes not. Most related post answers call for checking that the document is loaded or for jquery to be ready, and I've tried all of the permutations (currently both).  I'm referencing external .js files and .css .  Could the content of the function calls be so intensive that I should surround more operations with ready() checks?  Might it help to introduce a delay before performing operations on the DOM?

excerpt of all I think will be relevant:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ page import="semanticWeb.rep.concept.CommonNoun" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.ArrayList" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/chosen.css">
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/chosen.jquery.js"></script> 

            <Script>
                var theForm; 

                <%ArrayList<CommonNoun> commonNouns =(ArrayList<CommonNoun>)request.getAttribute("AllCommonNouns"); %>
                <%System.out.println("commonNouns: " + commonNouns);%>

                function addInheritanceElement() {

                    <%  for(int i = 0; i<commonNouns.size(); i++) {%>
                        $('<Option>')
                        .attr('value', "<%=commonNouns.get(i).getID()%>")
                        .text('<%=commonNouns.get(i).getName()%>')
                        .appendTo($("#superType"));                 
                    <%  } %>    

                    $(".chosen-select").chosen();
                }


            function testSelectLoading() {
                var newOptions = {
                        'red' : 'Red',
                        'blue' : 'Blue',
                        'green' : 'Green',
                        'yellow' : 'Yellow'
                    };
                    var selectedOption = 'green';

                    var select = $('<select>').appendTo(theForm);
                    var options;
                    if(select.prop) {
                      options = select.prop('options');

                    }
                    else {
                      options = select.attr('options');
                    }
                    $('option', select).remove();

                    $.each(newOptions, function(val, text) {
                        options[options.length] = new Option(text, val);
                    });
            }
</Script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <article>
            <Form id="myForm">
                <label for="superType">Inherit from Superclass: </label>

                <Select multiple data-placeholder="Must select one or more Common Nouns..." tabindex='5' class="chosen-select" id="superType" style="width: 300px;" >
                </Select>
            </Form>
        </article>      
        <script>
//          $(document).ready(addInheritanceElement());
            $(window).on("load", function() {
                theForm = document.getElementById("myForm");
                $( document ).ready(addInheritanceElement());
                $( document ).ready(testSelectLoading());
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried stress loading each of the external references, and found that my jquery.js was coming in intermittently.

https://forum.jquery.com/topic/what-happened-to-jquery-latest-min-js-on-code-jquery-com

found another hosting jquery, and all appears well when I updated the src call.